# Grid.Resources and Style in Windows 8 app programming

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows

I am new to window phone 8 programming.  I watched Channel 9's tutorial called Windows Phone 8 Development for Absolute Beginners, and now I am learning to write some simple code.
  Could anyone explain the relationship between the "Style" and the "Grid.Resources" in the sample code below?  I though that an inner tag, ie. Style, is a property of it's outer tag, ie. Grid.  But it doesn't make sense here since the outer tag, Grid.Resource, is actually a property.

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="Border">
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gold" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
  </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by _"How do I know if the tags below are a class, or a property"_?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know I can't use the "<" and ">" around a word when I post.  Let me reedit it.

Comment: Still don't understand. [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.style(v=vs.110).aspx) is a property of `FrameworkElement` not `Resources`. [`Resources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources(v=vs.110).aspx) is a dictionary that stores all the resources. Are you asking how it knows which `Style` to apply? In this case you create 2 implicit `Styles` for `Border` and `TextBlock` that later will be applied automatically to all `Grid`'s children, of these types, unless specified otherwise

Answer (score 0):

`TargetType` refers the System.Windows.Controls.Border [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.border.aspx) which is a class
`Property` refers to the property of the **Border** class.
In other words Style can only be based on a class, but that class can be a Property in other class like so:
ListView->View(GridView)
And your Style

```
<Style x:Key="sampleStyle" x:TargetType="GridView">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Setter>
```